# Linux Folder Group Permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a question about the permissions on a folder. I have the following Users and Groups:

```
User: home204
User: home370
Groups: testgroup
```

This are the folders i'm trying to change the permissions on:

```
# ls -l
drwxr-x---  4 web client   4096 Aug 18 09:09 home204/
drwxrwx---  5 web testgroup 4096 Aug 18 09:14 home370/
```

And here are the groups of the users:

```
# groups home370
home370 : client

# groups home204
home204 : client
```

I've changed the group on folder home370 to testgroup and changed permissions. However after loggin in as user 204 i still have full access
to both folders.

Here are the real details for the users in question

```
grep testgroup /etc/group
testgroup:x:1083

grep -E 'user204|user370' /etc/passwd
user204:x:1004:1004::/home/user204
user370:x:1004:1004::/home/user370
```

So my question is, how can i change a folders permissions that only members of a special group and root have access for read/write/execute on it?

Comment: With the permissions set like this, users that are not in the group "testgroup" shoulnd't be able to read/write into that directory or am i missing something here?

Comment: Well the thing is so far no user is member of the group testgroup and i still can read/write into home370 with user 204. 
 # grep testgroup /etc/group
 testgroup:x:1083:

# /etc/passwd
user204:x:1004:1004::/home/user204
user370:x:1004:1004::/home/user370

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was solved! the two Users have the same UID as User "web".